# What does a single pipe character in vuejs template handlebar expression do?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Example snippet:

```
              <span>
                {{ date | formatDate(groupHeadingFormat) }}
              </span>
```

I've tried looking at the vuejs and handlebars docs, but can't find any reference.

Comment: What's the vue version?

Comment: I don't believe this has anything to do with `handlebars.js`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This applies filters to the data on the left of pipe. Here is more info:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html

However, this is part of v2 and is obsolete in v3.

Comment: It's not just obsolete, filters were removed from v3. So if you do attempt to use it like this, it'll behave like [bitwise OR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_OR) and you'll probably end up confused.